# Is there a way to force NuGet to restore the latest package version during pipeline execution?

Tags: vb.net, azure-devops, nuget, yaml

We are using an internal NuGet feed in our Azure DevOps environment to host many different packages, which are consumed in many different projects. I would like to configure the pipeline so that whenever an internal package is referenced, it is always resolved to the latest version. All of the internal references are configured with wildcards in the PackageReference tag of the .vbproj file, like so:

```
<PackageReference Include="MyPackageName" Version="*" />
```

And the restore command in the YAML file is configured like so:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['ModifiedProject'], 'true'))
    displayName: 'NuGet restore'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      restoreSolution: '$(ModifiedProject.Directory)/$(ModifiedProject.Solution)'
      feedsToUse: 'select'
      vstsFeed: '[guid]/[guid]'
      noCache: true
```

The projects build successfully, but they still end up using the oldest version of the package instead of restoring the newest version. Is there a way to force the restore task to default to the newest package version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a workaround for this issue by using the [Azure DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/). My objective was to get the pipeline to flow through these basic steps:

1. After all build steps have been completed successfully, push the new package version into the artifact feed.
2. Use the REST API to unlist the old package version, leaving only the newest version available.
3. Because of the use of floating versions in the PackageReference tags, any projects that depend on these packages will then automatically pull the newest version when they are built in their respective pipelines.

I was only comfortable going this route because "deleting" a package in Azure doesn't really delete it, it just gets moved to the Recycle Bin. In the event there is a breaking change that is discovered post-push, we can always restore a previous version to the feed. Given that this process is being used exclusively for our 50+ internal packages with their own testing processes, it definitely seems like a safe route to go, and far more efficient than any other option I can find. However, I don't think I will mark this as a definitive answer to the question, because it still feels a bit hacky and I'd prefer there was a legitimate option to force newest versions in Azure's [NuGetCommand@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) task.

**Code**

As mentioned, I used Azure's well-documented REST API for these functions, particularly the areas governing [artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact%20%20details). Although there is a page dedicated to [deleting a package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget/delete%20package%20version) from a NuGet feed, I couldn't get their specification to work. I ended up inspecting the calls made from the UI and copying those, while still using my own token for authentication. This method does the history "trimming" I needed:

```
public void TrimPackageFeed(string feedName, string packageName)
{
    var packageVersions = GetPackageVersions(feedName, packageName);
    var deprecated = packageVersions.Where(x => !x.IsLatest && !x.IsDeleted)?.ToList();

    if (deprecated != null && deprecated.Any())
    {
        foreach (var version in deprecated)
        {
            var url = $"{version.Links.Feed.Value.Replace("feeds.dev.azure.com", "pkgs.dev.azure.com")}/nuget/packagesBatch";
            var payload = new AzurePackagePayload
            {
                Data = null,
                Operation = 2,
                Packages = new List<AzurePackagePayloadItem>
                {
                    new AzurePackagePayloadItem
                    {
                        ID = packageName,
                        Version = version.Version
                    }
                }
            };
            ApiRequest(url, Method.POST, null, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload));
        }
    }
}
```

I built this as a .NET Core 3.1 command line app, published as a self-contained executable within our build repo. I used C# because it's most familiar to me, but I'm confident this could be scripted in any language (probably even just PowerShell). I then appended the following task to the end of my YAML pipeline definition:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['ModifiedProject'], 'true'))
  displayName: 'Trim package feed'
  inputs:
    script: |
      AzureApiClient -action trim-package-feed -feed FeedNameHere -package $(ModifiedProject.AssemblyName)
    workingDirectory: 'Azure\AzureApiClient\Output'
    failOnStderr: true
```

The package gets pushed to the feed, then the assembly name is passed to my API client which will trim the historical versions and leaves only the new version available to restore.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here,  would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Comment: I have unlisted package from my NuGet feed, Still package is restoring while applying *nuget restore* command. Is any one has solution why is restoring?

Comment: @DhartiSutariya Unlisting a package version will remove it from the artifact's manifest so that it does not appear in the UI list of available versions, but it will keep hosting the package version and keep it available for direct download. If you want to make the package version inaccessible, you must use the 'Delete' option

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a self-hosted agent to run the pipeline, you can try to clear the local nuget cache, delete all the nuget packages in the global nuget cache under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages` or use [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders).

If the package to be consumed is just pushed into the feed, you need to wait for a while . There has to be a delay in populating packages on the feed.

In addition , you can try to use dotnet restore task to see if this issue still occurs . Here is a [ticket](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6640#issuecomment-421075740) with similar issue you can refer to .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried forcefully clearing the nuget cache, but nuget still resolves packages to the oldest version when performing a restore, which is the intended behavior. This makes sense with regard to third-party packages, but is not a useful solution for internal artifact feeds. I think I will end up using a script to work around this issue.

Comment: Add a specific version of a package to a project:`dotnet add ToDo.csproj package Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core -v 1.0.0` . Here is a [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package#examples).

Comment: That doesn't particularly help the current issue. To force a project to use a specific version, I would have to already know the version number I want to target and then execute that command against the project. If I was going to do that, I could just use NPM in Visual Studio to upgrade the project file. My whole objective for this post was trying to find a way to automate the upgrade during the build process so that manual intervention can be kept to a minimum